# Entity Framework throws "Collection was modified" when using observable collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have a class Employee, and class Company, which contains a (observable) list of employees.
The observable list is derived from List<>, and basically looks like this:

```
public class ObservableList<T> : List<T>
{
   // declaration of delegates and events here
   new public virtual void Add(T item)
        {
            CollectionChangingEventArgs<T> e = new CollectionChangingEventArgs<T>(new T[] { item }, ObservableListChangeAction.Adding);
            OnAdding(e);
            if (e.CancelAction)
                return;

            base.Add(item);

            CollectionChangedEventArgs<T> ed = new CollectionChangedEventArgs<T>(new T[] { item }, ObservableListChangeAction.Added);
            OnAdded(ed);
        }
}
```

The events are wired in Company constructor.
So the whole thing looks approximately like this:

```
public class Employee
    {
        // stuff here
    }

    public class Company
    {
        // stuff
        ObservableList<Employee> employees = new ObservableList<Employee>();
        public ObservableList<Employee> Employees { get { return this.employees; } }

        public Company()
        {
            Employees.Adding += new ObservableList<Employee>.CollectionChangingEventHandler(Employees_Adding);
        }

        void Employees_Adding(object sender, CollectionChangingEventArgs<Employee> e)
        {
            // do some checks.. none alter the collection
            *edit*
           // I have a line that does this:
           **employee.Employer = this;**
          //So if the employer was saved prior to this point, it errors out.
        }   
    }
```

Now, if I do this:

```
Company c = new Company();
Employee e = new Employee();
c.Employees.Adding(e);
c.Save();
```

it works fine.

If, however, I save employee first, like this:

```
   Company c = new Company();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.Save();
    c.Employees.Adding(e);
    c.Save();
```

then EF throws an exception: *Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.*

Save() method comes from a base class, basically does this:

```
  this.dbContext.Set<T>().Add(instance);
  dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This is a stack trace:

> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PerformAdd(IList`1 entries)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean
>   force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action,
>   EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)

If I change ObservableList to List<> - it works. If I don't hook up events - it works.
So basically EF doesn't like the events for some reason. 
When I'm saving the Company, they're not fired, btw.

I am confused.. Any idea what could be causing this ?

Comment: `List<T>` isn't really meant to be inherited from - take a hint on `Add()` not being declared virtual

Comment: Events don't want to be fired by the Company :)

Comment: Can you use the built in ObservableCollection instead of making your own?  Does it have the same issue?

Comment: Should `Company.Employees` be mapped to the DB? It is readonly and has only a getter? What happens if you comment out the code in `Employees_Adding` (but let the handler wired up)? And why oh why do you have a `Save` and a `DbContext` reference in your entities? `SaveChanges` saves a whole unit of work and not single entities. It's not the responsibility of a single entity to save a whole bunch of different entities and relationships.

Comment: @BrokenGlass Not relevant to this, but good point regardless.. Switched it to inherit from ICollection.

Comment: @cadrell0 ObservableCollection doesn't let you stop the action. So it's useless to me.

Comment: @Slauma Everything is mapped.  I was trying to make use of IRepo and Active Record, hence the Save method. Not sure if it's a great idea, still experimenting, but works pretty well so far.
Anywho, found the offending line. When I add employee to the company, the event handler for adding does this:
employees[i].Employer = this; ( this is a company )

So if the employee was saved prior to this line, it throws an exception.

Comment: @Eugene: You should edit this line into your question and highlight it, seems to be important info. (Or is the problem solved for you now?)

Comment: @Slauma I know where and when it fails.. Don't exactly understand why.

Comment: @Eugene: I can only say that EF fixes relationships itself internally at certain points (`DetectChanges`, `Add`, `Remove`, `SaveChanges` and more). It means that you usually don't need to set the other side of a relationship. So, `employee.Employer = this` is redundant if you have added to the collection with `c.Employees.Add(e);`. I could imagine that there occurs some conflict between that automatic fixup and your manual fixup, but I'm not able to understand in detail. Did you notice any problem when you remove that line `employee.Employer = this` from your handler? If not, remove it!

Comment: @Eugene If you are stopping the action, that could be the issue.  Whenever you modify a property on an Entity, it calls something like OnEntityModifying before and OnEntityModified after.  You cannot modify any other properties between these two calls.  I imagine something similar is happening when you modify your collection.  This could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: It's possibly a bug in EF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536459/ef-4-1-and-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-exce/7539855#7539855 and has likely nothing to do with using event handlers.