# EF 4.3 Behaving Differently Between Azure and Local Dev

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-4, azure-web-roles

I just deployed my web app, that works beautifully locally, to Windows Azure and I'm getting an error that is perplexing.  On Azure my code is failing on the following line:

```
  context.Dogs.Add(entity);
```

The error I'm getting is:

**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute**

I understand that there is a known bug ([Entity framework Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250868/entity-framework-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)), but does anyone have any insights why it would work well locally, but not on Azure?

Comment: Do you have .NET 4.5 installed on your local development environment? Are you targeting .NET 4.5 on Azure?

Comment: @JamesHarris I do have 4.5 installed on my local dev environment. Both the application locally and the Azure app pool are targeting 4.0.

Comment: Ahhh, installing.Net 4.5 still makes changes to .NET 4.0, and silently fixes bugs in the .NET Framework, which may include the behavior your application demonstrating. Try targeting 4.5 on Azure. Unless your deploying to an environment that has or can install .NET 4.5, you should never have it installed on your development PC to avoid these "silent fixes".

Comment: @JamesHarris  That seems to have fixed this error.  Thank you.  If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I've added the comment as an answer, hopefully this will also help others who might encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing .Net 4.5 makes changes to .NET 4.0, and fixes bugs in the .NET Framework, even for applications that target 4.0.

This may include the behavior your application demonstrating.

Try targeting 4.5 on Azure to ensure that your deployed application also receives these fixes.

Unless your deploying to an environment that has or can install .NET 4.5, you should *never* have it installed on your development PC to avoid these type of bugs caused by "silent fixes".