# EF 5 - Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-5

I want to insert some test data into my database with Entity Framework 5. It works fine - only if I **uncomment** 1 line of code:

```
var query = DbContext.Set<User>().AsQueryable();
query = query.Include("Tabs.Boxes");
query = query.Where(u => u.Name == "test_guy");
User test_guy = query.Single();

Tab mainTab = new Tab() 
{ 
    TabName = "Main tab",
    Order = 1,
};
Tab otherTab = new Tab()
{
    TabName = "Test Guy's another tab",
    Order = 2
};

test_guy.Tabs.Add(mainTab);
test_guy.Tabs.Add(otherTab);

DbContext.SaveChanges();   // --> If I comment this out, everything breaks!

mainTab.Boxes = new Boxes();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Box box1 = new Box()
    {
        Author = test_guy
    };
    mainTab.Boxes.Add(box1);
}

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If I **comment out** that SaveChanges call, I will get an exception:
`Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

I just want to know, what is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: At which line does the exception occur?

Comment: At the SaveChanges call (the last line)
The exception comes from the DetectChanges (which is called by SaveChanges inside the Entity Framework)
Maybe this is a scenario like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536459/ef-4-1-and-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-exc)?
But I don't have circles in the object graph in the upper code...

Comment: Try moving the line `mainTab.Boxes = new Boxes();` to the initialization of `mainTab` at the top of your code,

Comment: I have tried that, not works... :(

Comment: OK, what if you move `test_guy.Tabs.Add(mainTab);` to just before the last `SaveChanges`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding boxes to mainTab before you add mainTab to test_guy and have only one call to savechanges() method as shown below:

```
var query = DbContext.Set<User>().AsQueryable();
query = query.Include("Tabs.Boxes");
query = query.Where(u => u.Name == "test_guy");
User test_guy = query.Single();

Tab mainTab = new Tab() 
{ 
    TabName = "Main tab",
    Order = 1,
};
Tab otherTab = new Tab()
{
    TabName = "Test Guy's another tab",
    Order = 2
};

mainTab.Boxes = new Boxes();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Box box1 = new Box()
    {
        Author = test_guy
    };
    mainTab.Boxes.Add(box1);
}

test_guy.Tabs.Add(mainTab);
test_guy.Tabs.Add(otherTab);

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive had the same exception - in my case the reason was in duplication of associations on dbModel.