# DbContext.Add error,Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm looking for answers, but I didn't find any. So when I add second element in `context.Customers`, I get an Exception:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Why? Any help will be much appreciated.

My code:

```
public class CompanyInitalizer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CompanyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(CompanyContext context)
    {
        var contacts = new List<Contact>
        {
            new Contact {
                Vezetéknév="Nagy",
                Keresztnév="János",
                Beosztás="alkalmazott",
                Email="nagy.janos@default1.com",
                Telefonszám="06361254452"
            },

            new Contact {
                Vezetéknév="Kiss",
                Keresztnév="Ferenc",
                Beosztás="alkalmazott",
                Email="kiss.ferenc@default1.com",
                Telefonszám="06361254452"
            }
        };

       contacts.ForEach(d => context.Contacts.Add(d));
       context.SaveChanges();

        var events = new List<Event>
        {
            new Event {
                Időpont=DateTime.Parse("12/31/2010"), 
                Típusa="Tárgyalás",
                Leírás="Éves költségvetés"
            },

            new Event {
                Időpont=DateTime.Parse("12/31/2010"), 
                Típusa="Tárgyalás",
                Leírás="Éves költségvetés"
            }
        };

      events.ForEach(d => context.Events.Add(d));
      context.SaveChanges();


        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {
                Cégnév ="Default1.Kft",
                Irányítószám= 1012,
                Város="Budapest",
                Cím="Tavasz utca 54.",
                Weblap="http://www.default1.com",
                Telefonszám="06361254452",
                Contacts= contacts,
                Events=events
            },

            new Customer {
                Cégnév ="Default2.Kft",
                Irányítószám= 2440,
                Város="Százhalombatta",
                Cím="Tél utca 34.",
                Weblap="http://www.default1.com",
                Telefonszám="063623254452",
                Contacts=contacts,
                Events=events
            }
        };


    customers.ForEach(d => context.Customers.Add(d)); //Throw exception here!
    context.SaveChanges();           
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536459/ef-4-1-and-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-exc - This might help you

Comment: Most likely Same issue as mentioned by ssilas.  Some circular reference EF doesnt like perhaps.  The other post has a lot of detail. Suggest you move to answer SSILAS

Comment: This dont work, how can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem solved!
 Same entities added to Customers. I make new contacts and events entity and add to Customers.**